# Extract attached files from a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, attachment

Is there a way to extract all the attached files in a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each list item, and get each attachment.

```
List<SPAttachment> attachments = new List<SPAttachment>();
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["My List"];

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
    attachments.AddRange(item.Attachments.Cast<SPAttachment>());
}
```